# Extract Particular element based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I Have a xml file, It contain a number of namespace from this xml file I have to copy an element which contain text = Cash when i put condition on it. then output generate nothing Please help me out.
1. I have to Extract the element which have only text = Cash.

```
<link:linkbase xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd">
    <link:roleRef xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        roleURI="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/role/label/axisDefault"
        xlink:href="us-roles-2018-01-31.xsd#axisDefault" xlink:type="simple"/>
    <link:labelLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/link" xlink:type="extended">
        <link:label id="lab_Cash_label1_en-US" xlink:label="lab_Cash"
            xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label" xlink:type="resource" xml:lang="en-US"
            >Cash</link:label>
        <link:loc xlink:href="us-gaap-2018-01-31.xsd#us-gaap_AOCIAttributableToParentAbstract"
            xlink:label="loc_AOCIAttributableToParentAbstract" xlink:type="locator"/>
        <link:label id="lab_Cash_label2_en-US" xlink:label="lab_Cash"
            xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label" xlink:type="resource" xml:lang="en-US"
            >Cash</link:label>

        <link:label id="lab_AOCIAttributableToParentAbstract_label_en-US"
            xlink:label="lab_AOCIAttributableToParentAbstract"
            xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label" xlink:type="resource" xml:lang="en-US"
            >AOCI Attributable to Parent [Abstract]</link:label>
        <link:labelArc order="1.0" xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/concept-label"
            xlink:from="loc_AOCIAttributableToParentAbstract"
            xlink:to="lab_AOCIAttributableToParentAbstract" xlink:type="arc"/>
        <link:label id="lab_Cash_label_en-US" xlink:label="lab_Cash"
            xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label" xlink:type="resource" xml:lang="en-US"
            >Cash</link:label>
    </link:labelLink>
</link:linkbase>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xlink:href="us-roles-2018-01-31.xsd#axisDefault"
    xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/link"
    xml:lang="en-US"
    xlink:type="resource"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="link:*[text()='_Cash']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're matching `_Cash` instead of `Cash`.

Comment: It is Cash But I am still facing porblem.

Comment: I tested it and the result consists of the three elements with the value `Cash`.